# how to set the default value for the input from a db in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an input of type checkout and I want to use firestore to get the default value and then put that value in the state and be able to change it and update the store. this is how I thought about it for now.

```
[visible,setVisible] = useState(false)
const data = commingFromFirebase();
return(
  <div>
   {
     data.map(el => <input type="checkbox" defaultValue={el.visible} value={visible} 
     onChange={e => setVisible(!visible)}/>
   }

  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`defaultValue` cannot be used with a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) - i.e. one where `value` is controlled by props or state.

`defaultValue` is only used on [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Because your input is of the controlled type - a change to props or state will change the state of the component - you **cannot** use `defaultValue`.

Note: In your case, you are using a checkbox so the props are `checked` (equivalent to `value`) and `defaultChecked` (equivalent to `defaultValue`), as indicated in the other answer.

Comment: ty, for the explanation of defaultValue Adam

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function that returns a boolean and pass it to the checkbox as a [checked](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props) parameter. That way it will be marked if it returns true and unmarked if it is false.

Should be something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked}
```

Comment: ye but i want that i can set the default from firestore and be able to change it through the state